# How to manage many nodes on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Some of the tools we use for our app-building can only run once per user instance. To still be able to make use of the machines, we use multiple users, each connected as its own node. We will upgrade our macOS-infrastructure and therefore will have up to 30 different users/nodes on serveral machines.
I tried the "Mac plugin", but it has serveral issues and it's not very common. We have the same issue with our linux (RHEL) machines. How would you manage this many nodes?

Comment: Have you seen [_Using Jenkins agents_](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/) and [_Scaling Jenkins_](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/scaling/) already? Perhaps considering a config distribution tool (with your users' machines as clients) like Ansible, cdist, CFEngine, Puppet, Saltstack is also a good idea (to keep the Java installation which is required on the agents the same, for instance).